# What state_union class is used for

Tags: python, nltk

what is this class's return type? What are its public methods and its general application?
Where I can read on it?
Couldn't find it at http://www.nltk.org/ docs at all!
While other classes, like `PunktSentenceTokenizer`, are present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In abstract, it is a sentence tokenizer(grouping in sentence, or words), depending on unsupervised machine learning.As I start to learn more about NLP, I found this website is helpful. 
https://pythonprogramming.net/part-of-speech-tagging-nltk-tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

In a python console exec:

```
import nltk
help(nltk)
help(nltk.PunktSentenceTokenizer)
```